# Swagger override @JsonProperty("") annotation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

In my code I am using **@JsonProperty("")** for naming fields in JSON response.

Like

```
@JsonProperty(value = "UserData")private List<UserEntity> userEntities;
```

And I am getting API response correctly ( that filed name is '**UserData**')
but in swagger HTML file the filed name is getting as '**user_data**'

In my application.properties following properties are set SNAKE_CASE as default.

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve this. I need the field name as in the @JsonProperty(value = "**UserData**")

Comment: Add after `@JsonProperty` the following annotation `@ApiModelProperty(value = "the user data")`

Comment: @JonathanJohx I added `@ApiModelProperty(value = "UserData")`. but still I am getting `user_data`

Comment: What swagger version are you using?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I am using Swagger 2.9.2. And this issue is due to a bug in springfox https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2904

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
@ApiModelProperty(name = "UserData")
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still, I am getting `user_data`. If I set `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` in application.properties, I will get correct name `UserData`. But I cannot change application.properties

Comment: Could you remove completely the ```spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy```  then?

Comment: We need SNAKE_CASE as default, so the value of spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy cannot be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the bug in Springfox regarding to this [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2904) that is still **Open**.
If you really want to achieve this for the moment, I think you could annotate ```@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)``` to your POJO instead of using ```spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy```.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried @JsonProperty("UserData")? as per [this post](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2635)